# Are The Incredibles comics canon?

Tags: comics, canon, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

The film *The Incredibles* has had two types of sequels: the film *Incredibles 2* and a set of comic books (can't find their plot on Wikipedia, just the title "The Incredibles: Family Matters"). I seem to remember reading somewhere about the comic books ending with the family being cast out of the city because of the Underminer. However, the trailers for the film seem to have the Underminer defeated and the family back in hero work (at least at the beginning).

If the new film is canon, can the comic books be canon as well, or do they contradict each other?

Comment: I haven't read the comic, but I've watched the movie. If what you say of the comic is correct, it doesn't necessarily contradict the movie. Your idea of what happens in the movie based on the trailer isn't entirely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comics that were produced during the period [between the making of The Incredibles and prior to the release of *The Incredibles 2*](https://the-incredibles.fandom.com/wiki/The_Incredibles:_Comic_Series) were treated as being entirely non-canon by the studio, which the relegated them to oblivion by making the film incompatible with the comics.

For example, in the Boom! Studios *The Incredibles* comics, the family encounter aliens, fight robots from the future and continue to operate as a family of costumed superheroes whereas in *The Incredibles 2*, we don't see them doing any of these things.

[image]

Conversely, Disney seem to have made some effort to have the newer [*The Incredibles 2* comics](https://the-incredibles.fandom.com/wiki/Crisis_in_Mid-Life!_%26_other_stories_Issue_1) tie into the film more closely by setting the scenes in their new house, working with the powers that Jack-Jack has shown, etc. although I think we can reasonably assume that these will also be 'man-overboard' as soon as *The Incredibles 3* gets the [green light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredibles_(franchise)#Future_films).